# How to calculate perplexity for a language model using Pytorch

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm fine-tuning GPT-2 model for language generation task using huggingface Transformers library-pytorch, and I need to calculate an evaluation score(perplexity) for the fine-tuned model. But I'm not sure how that can be done using loss. I would like to know how perplexity can be calculated for the model with sum_loss or mean loss or any other suggestions are also welcome. Any help is appriciated.

**Edit:**

```
outputs = model(article_tens, labels=article_tens)

        loss, prediction_scores = outputs[:2]                        
        loss.backward()
        sum_loss = sum_loss + loss.detach().data
```

given above is how I calculate loss for each batch of data for the fine-tuning task.

```
sum loss 1529.43408203125
loss 4.632936000823975
prediction_scores tensor([[[-11.2291,  -9.2614, -11.8575,  ..., -18.1927, -17.7286, -11.9215],
         [-67.2786, -63.5928, -70.7110,  ..., -75.3516, -73.8672, -67.6637],
         [-81.1397, -80.0295, -82.9357,  ..., -83.7913, -85.7201, -78.9877],
         ...,
         [-85.3213, -82.5135, -86.5459,  ..., -90.9160, -90.4393, -82.3141],
         [-44.2260, -43.1702, -49.2296,  ..., -58.9839, -55.2058, -42.3312],
         [-63.2842, -59.7334, -61.8444,  ..., -75.0798, -75.7507, -54.0160]]],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<UnsafeViewBackward>)
```

The above given is when loss is printed for a batch only

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As shown in [Wikipedia - Perplexity of a probability model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity), the formula to calculate the perplexity of a probability model is:

[image: Perplexity Formula]

The exponent is the cross-entropy. While logarithm base 2 (*b = 2*) is traditionally used in cross-entropy, deep learning frameworks such as PyTorch use the natural logarithm (*b = e*).

Therefore, to get the perplexity from the cross-entropy loss, you only need to apply [`torch.exp`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.exp) to the loss.

```py
perplexity = torch.exp(loss)
```

The mean loss is used in this case (the *1 / N* part of the exponent) and if you were to use the sum of the losses instead of the mean, the perplexity would get out of hand (exceedingly large), which can easily surpass the maximum floating point number, resulting in infinity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've applied an edit to show how my coding is done, and do you suggest that I can calculate the perplexity for the loss given in the code above, since the values for loss gives me negative values mostly. thank you.

Comment: Yes, from the `loss`. The `prediction_scores` are not part of the loss, they are the raw logits for each token and if you want to get the probabilities for each token you can apply softmax to them.

Comment: Thanks again for cleaning out my doubts :)

Comment: Will it be correct if I calculate sum of perplexities at each iteration and get the mean perplexity by dividing it by the no. of iterations at the end?

Comment: No, because `torch.exp(x / N) != torch.exp(x) / N` the latter is exponentially larger. You should get the mean loss across the entire dataset, and then calculate the perplexity from that.